# C# Обмен данными между формами

Tags: c#, формы

Помогите разобраться. Пишу программу на С# в которой от Form1 наследуется Form2 и Form3. В ходе работы нужно передать полученные данные из Form2 на TextBox'ы Form3. Не могу понять как это реализовать. Передача должна выполняться в обработчике события

Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

[image: схема]

Все еще не понимаю как правильно сделать.

В главной форме создаю 2 наследующих формы по клику, в одной передаю ссылку на другую

```
        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Eventer EventerForm = new Eventer();
        EventerForm.Show();
        Main MainForm = new Main(EventerForm);
        MainForm.Show();

    }
```

В конструкторе второй формы принимаю ссылку на третью

```
        public Main(L5f.Eventer EventerForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ex1 = EventerForm.textBox1.Text;
        ey1 = EventerForm.textBox2.Text;
        ex2 = EventerForm.textBox3.Text;
        ey2 = EventerForm.textBox4.Text;
    }
static string ex1, ey1, ex2, ey2 = "yahho";
```

но очевидно это должно работать не так. Нужно в поля EventerForm передать информацию из MainForm

Comment: вообще-то наследование не отвечает за передачу данных!

Comment: Передавайте в конструктор одной формы ссылку на другую. Там запоминаете ее в поле класса формы. А в обработчике обращаетесь к этому полю и передаете данные, например, вызывая метод.

Comment: Как альтернативный вариант, можно записывать формы в статические поля при их загрузке, это просто, но это костыль.

Comment: Я кончено никак не помогу вам своим комментарием, но, пожалуйста, на будущее, почитайте об архитектуре и слоях приложения. Достаточно будет понимание паттерна MVC. После это вы никогда не будете задавать такие вопросы. А если короче, то вам надо дойти до понимания того, что код, отвечающий за логику отображения данных, не должен отвечать за логику манипулирования данных.

Answer (score -1):

делаеш метод расширения

```
public static class ShareForms
    {
        public  static TForm GetForm<TForm>(this Form f) where  TForm: Form, new()
        {

            var formT = Application
                .OpenForms
                .OfType<TForm>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return formT;
        }
    }
```

и потом  вызываем

```
var value = this.GetForm<Form10>().Form10ValueString;
```

Если есть нескольок класов с одним именем

```
var value = this.GetForm<NameSpacePath.Form10>().Form10ValueString;
```

Comment: А если там будет несколько `Form10`?

Comment: лол это как можеть несколько Form10 Ну если в другом namespace только и то это не проблема

Comment: Я имею в виду несколько экземпляров, а не классов. Мы же можем написать `new Form10().Show()` несколько раз.

Comment: не совсем понятно зачем это вообще нужно 10 раз одно откноо ткрывать. тоже не прроблема изменить методы что бы он возвращал коллекцию окон

Comment: То что тип одинаковый, не означает, что и экземпляры будут одинаковые. Вон кнопки все тоже типа `Button`, однако ж разные.

Comment: не понятен смысл вопроса. Конкретно можно указать ситуацию

Comment: например, 10 окон с кодом в визуал студии, 10 окон с чатом в скайпе, 10 вкладок в браузере, 10 экскель документов, 10 открытых окон с письмами из outlook... и тд - окна одного типа открыты несколько раз

Comment: ну то что вы перечислили точно не из этой задачи. Эти окно уже через winapi выцеплять надо.я про самописное приложение и где будет 10 окон и пример взаимодействия. Сложновато сделать что универсальное что бы под все случаи подходило.

Comment: ну я не про задачу, я просто про примеры, где может быть такое, что одинковые окна будут открыты несколько раз - просто, чтобы вы знали, что это нормально. Вот, например, мой [pet](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient) проект с тем же функционалом, или [другой pet проект](https://github.com/tym32167/dotnetnotepad) - везде можно открыть одно и то же коно несколько раз и это будет иметь смысл